# Controling ItemChecked event after filtering data in a CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom UserControl that has a TextBox, a Button and a CheckedListBox.
the DataSource of the CheckedListBox is a DataTable - m_CheckBoxItems.
TextBox has a TextChanged event on it.
every letter entered into the TextBox causes the DataSource to change according to what values where found.

```
DataRow[] filteredRows;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
            {
                DataTable tmp = m_ChecBoxItems.Copy();
                ((ListBox)checkedListBox).DataSource = new BindingSource(tmp, null);
            }
            else
            {
                filteredRows = m_ChecBoxItems.Select("Text like '" + filter + "%'");
                DataTable tmp = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
                ((ListBox)checkedListBox).DataSource = new BindingSource(tmp, null);
            }

            ((ListBox)checkedListBox).DisplayMember = "Text";
            ((ListBox)checkedListBox).ValueMember = "Id";
```

now, my problem is that when i click one of the options, the OnItemClicked event fires and checks the selected index according to what the old DataSource was and then after that it get into the checkedListBox_ItemCheck event where i have some code to change the checkstate of the correct index that i intentionally click, based on where it was before the DataSource changed.

for example: m_CheckBoxItems has 100 items in it. i type "d" and the datasource changes to only values that start with "d". then i click one of the items (lets say on the second row) and then inssues the chaos. the OnItemCheck event fires containing the index that was clicked according to what i **see** i.e: 1 and checks that index. **then** it goes into checkedListBox_ItemCheck event with my own code in it and checks the original index that belonged to the specific row that i chose (lets say it was index 34).

so now i have **two** items checked instead of just the one that i wanted (index 34)

with every item check i also put that datarow into a list of selected datarows for future handling so that part is good, i get the row that i clicked on (index 34) and not the row that was checked by mistake (index 1).

this is my question:
how can i prevent this situation?
how can i make the checkedlistbox to check only the row that i wanted and not two rows?

Comment: What's `OnItemCheck` when you have `checkedListBox_ItemCheck`? It's better to share the code.

Comment: OnItemCheck is an event fired before ItemCheck is fired. it's inherited from listbox control by checkedlistbox. i did not create this event and i don't have my own code in there.

Comment: You should not check/uncheck items in your `ItemCheck` event. Also be aware that *the check state is not updated until after the ItemCheck event occurs.*